# Extending UM91214B to support more channels

Tags: multiplexer, remote

In this circuit's description, It is given that we can extend the circuit easily to generate up to 12 DTMF signals. How can that be done?

[image: Reference Design]

Answer (score 1):

The four outputs actually give a binary code out, so there are 16 possible combinations. This circuit only uses the codes where only 1 but is high:

```
0001  
0010  
0100  
1000
```

If you would use one of the other codes you would switch 2 or more outputs simultaneously.

What you want is a 4-to-16 demultiplexer, like the [74HC154](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT154.pdf). This will give you a **low** pulse on one of the 16 outputs when the corresponding DTMF code is sent. The original schematic gives an active **high** pulse. This means that either you have to invert the polarities of all the outputs, or that the output will only switch when the key is released instead of being pressed.

For the transmitter you simply have to add extra buttons in the rows/columns matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot @_Oli Glaser and @stevenvh. I figured out from the datasheet of um91214 on how to generate different codes using row-col short circuiting. Thanks a lot for the help with the receiver side.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the circuit [description](http://www.electronic-circuits-diagrams.com/remotecontrolsimages/remotecontrolsckt5.shtml) it talks about what needs to be done to increase the number of channels.
The transmitter would need the corresponding buttons added to it, and the receiver would need a 4 to 16 [multiplexer](http://web.mit.edu/6.115/www/datasheets/74hc154.pdf) attached (note inversion mentioned by Stephen, maybe a negative edge triggered flip flop could be used - random example in DIP [here](http://datasheets.hypertriton.com/sn74hc112.pdf)) so if the 4 outs are e.g. 0110, rather than turning switch 2 and 4 on, it will turn only switch 6 on (2 + 4 = 6)